# Match making in online games

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am implementing an online game. For matching two users I am currently updating a table with users id. A php program shall run infinitely and if there are more than 2 rows in the table it matches them and enters both the names in another row so that users can get updated by fetching from that table. I am not well versed with php. Is there a better idea for implementing this?

```
while(true) {
    $cmd = "select * from user_data.request";
    $value = $conn->query($cmd);
    $rows = $value->num_rows;
    if ($rows<2) {
        sleep(4);
        continue;
    }
    $m = 1;
    while($rows > 1) {
        $row1 = $value->fetch_assoc();
        $row2 = $value->fetch_assoc();
        $cmd = "insert into user_data.match values (\"".$row1['id']."\",\"".$row2['id']."\",".$m.")";
        $value = $conn->query($cmd);
        $rows = $rows-2;
        $cmd = "delete from user_data.request where id=\"".$row1['id']."\" || id=\"".$row2['id']."\"";
    }
}
```

Now the user receives the updated table details.

```
while(true) {
    $cmd = "select * from user_data.match where id1=\"".$u1."\" || id2=\"".$u1."\"";
    $value = $conn->query($cmd);
    $rows = $value->num_rows;
    if ($rows == 0) {
        sleep(2);
        continue;
    }
    $row = $value->fetch_assoc();
    $user1 = $row['id1'];
    $user2 = $row['id2'];
    break;
}
```

Comment: use `OR` instead of `||`.And post any error on your php

Comment: You should also look into using parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that.